# How to detect line separation in a td content in Jquery?

Tags: jquery

If I have a td that contains data split/wrapped in two lines (without any br), is there a way to detect this using Jquery? For example, get the td where data is split and color it red.

Is it possible?

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
very long texttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt that will wrap in two lines
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I have tried with fetching the height of the row that increases due to the wrapped text and then applying the necessary logic and it works but I was wondering if there is a simpler/better way to do this?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: can you add the HTML for `I have a td that contains data split/wrapped in two lines (with nor br)` ? what do you mean by "with nor br"?

Comment: Sorry. I meant without any br. Sure, I'll edit the question.

Comment: do you have any CSS combined? I mean in this case if the view or width of `<td>` is wide enough it will not wrap in two lines. So we need a value to compare against, this could be height you expect for TD or it could be the exceeding number of characters inside the td? which do you prefer?

Comment: The latter. Suppose, the width of the table is 50% or some value that automatically wraps  the text. In that case, how will be detect it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about something like this to get you started?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  var tdMaxChars = 50;

  $('table td').each(function(){
    
    console.log('length of text in td: ' + $(this).text().length)
    
    if($(this).text().length >= tdMaxChars) {
      $(this).addClass('td-max-chars-exceeded')
    }
  });
});
```

```css
table { border: collapse; }
table td { border: solid 1px gray; }

.td-max-chars-exceeded {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>very long texttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt that will wrap in two lines</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>very short text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: To make it more precise you can also get the width of the td, write the text to a hidden field and check if the width of the hidden field is greater then the width of the td.